# how to make custom serializer which can handle nested post data for Create API endpoint?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Due to unique business needs, I have to customize the Create API endpoint.
Default behavior in django-rest-framework is like this.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    fieldA = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    fieldB = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)
    ... ...

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'

class CustomerListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
```

post data

```
{
    fieldA: 1,
    fieldB: 'some string'
}
```

it sends respond with Created status

```
{
    id: 1,
    fieldA: 1,
    fieldB: 'some string'
}
```

However, I want to post data with nested data and validate

```
{
    "customer": {
        "fieldA": 1,
        "fieldB": "some string"
    }
}
```

Expected response data should be

```
{
    "customer": {
        "id": 1,
        "fieldA": 1,
        "fieldB": "some string"
    }
}
```

Also validation should show nested error messages

```
{
    "customer": "customer field is required"
}

{
    "customer": {
        "fieldA": ["filedA is required"],
    }
}
```

How can I archieve this?

Comment: How about this [package](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my revised approach.  It creates new instance using serializer and sends nested validation error messages.

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'


class CustomerView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        customer = request.data.get('customer', None)
        if not customer:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'customer': 'customer field is required'})

        serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=customer)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False)
        if serializer.errors:
            error = {
                'customer': serializer.errors
            }
            return Response(error, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        data = serializer.save()
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Validation errors:

```
{
    "customer": "customer field is required"
}

{
    "customer": {
        "fieldA": ["filedA is required"],
    }
}
```

Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an ApiView and validate each single data by iterating.
If all the data is valid then create the objects.

Example:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'

class CustomerListCreateAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        customers = request.data.get('customer', None)
        for customer in customers:
            validated_data = CustomerSerializer(data=customer)
            # if invalid Raise Validation error 
        objects = []
        for customer in customers:
            validated_data = CustomerSerializer(data=customer)
            customer = Customer.objects.create(validated_data)
            objects.append(customer.id)

        return Response(
            CustomerSerializer(Customer.objects.filter(id__in=objects), many=True).data)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, @uzzal-h-mohammad. I assumed request data is nested object, but your solution for array of customers make sense to me.
I've added validation logic and posted my own answer